# Why does npm v3 installation fails on Windows?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, apiconnect

In order to satisfy the per-requisites for IBM ApiConnect Developer Toolkit installation on Windows, I was attempting to upgrade my `npm` to version 3 using the command -

```
 npm install -g npm
```

Here is the snippet from npm-debug.log  -

```
2 info using npm@2.15.8
3 info using node@v4.4.7
4 verbose install initial load of C:\Users\arindch.WIPRO\AppData\Roaming\npm\package.json
5 verbose readDependencies loading dependencies from C:\Users\arindch.WIPRO\AppData\Roaming\npm\package.json
6 silly cache add args [ 'npm', null ]
7 verbose cache add spec npm
8 silly cache add parsed spec Result {
8 silly cache add   raw: 'npm',
8 silly cache add   scope: null,
8 silly cache add   name: null,
8 silly cache add   rawSpec: 'npm',
8 silly cache add   spec: 'E:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\npm',
8 silly cache add   type: 'local' }
9 silly addLocalTarball shasum (computed) 3ad8081c76f557dfe66cfd96faedc6b9bf684c51
10 verbose addTmpTarball E:\Program Files\nodejs\npm not in flight; adding
11 verbose correctMkdir C:\Users\arindch.WIPRO\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
12 verbose addTmpTarball validating metadata from E:\Program Files\nodejs\npm
13 verbose tar unpack E:\Program Files\nodejs\npm
14 verbose tar unpacking to C:\Users\ARINDC~1.WIP\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-4064-003cc9de\unpack-dbf5b9c7759f
15 silly gentlyRm C:\Users\ARINDC~1.WIP\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-4064-003cc9de\unpack-dbf5b9c7759f is being purged
16 verbose gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking C:\Users\ARINDC~1.WIP\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-4064-003cc9de\unpack-dbf5b9c7759f
17 silly gunzTarPerm modes [ '777', '666' ]
18 error not a package E:\Program Files\nodejs\npm
19 error addLocal Could not install E:\Program Files\nodejs\npm
20 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\ARINDC~1.WIP\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-4064-003cc9de\unpack-dbf5b9c7759f\package.json'
20 verbose stack     at Error (native)
21 verbose cwd E:\Program Files\nodejs
22 error Windows_NT 10.0.10586
23 error argv "E:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "E:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "npm"
24 error node v4.4.7
25 error npm  v2.15.8
26 error path C:\Users\ARINDC~1.WIP\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-4064-003cc9de\unpack-dbf5b9c7759f\package.json
27 error code ENOENT
28 error errno -4058
29 error syscall open
30 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\ARINDC~1.WIP\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-4064-003cc9de\unpack-dbf5b9c7759f\package.json'
30 error enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
30 error enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
31 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]
```

Answer (score 1):

First, ensure that you can execute scripts on your system by running the following command from an elevated PowerShell. To run PowerShell as Administrator, click Start, search for PowerShell, right-click PowerShell and `select Run as Administrator`. The Run the following command

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force
```

Then, to install and use this Windows upgrader tool, run (also from an elevated PowerShell or cmd.exe):

```
npm install --global --production npm-windows-upgrade
npm-windows-upgrade
```

Finally verify the npm version in normal cmd.exe or PowerShell by typing

```
npm -v
```

Answer (score 0):

chattopadhya,
I faced the same kind of issues, and my solution was:

1. Install NodeJS 6.14.0 (LTS) with NPM 3
2. Install [Windows Build Tools](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools), version 3.1.0: `npm install -g --production windows-build-tools@3.1.0`
3. **This task will render your NodeJS into an unsafe state**: set an environment variable `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` to discard TLS certificates validation. (**Note: I can't and will not be held responsible for any consequences of this action in machines other than my own.**)
4. Finally installed API Connect package without any issue: `npm install -g apiconnect`.

Hope it helps. :)